# Access to javascript variable through android (webview)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I'm converting a website to android application using webview.
The website is composed of many div tags and in each div there is span tag which allows the user to print the contents of that div when he clicks on it(on span)

When user clicks on span (In the application) it just view the content of div
How can I do the printing process in android?

There is a JQuery method that extracts the div content and print it :

I'm wondering that if I can access "parentPrint" through android then I can print it .But when and where should I access it ?And How ?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //print by click
    //printID is the class of span tags
        $('.PrintID').live('click', function () {
            var parentPrint; // will hold the content of the div
            var tempPrint = $(this).parents('.model').clone(true);
            $(tempPrint).find('.PrintID').text('');
            $(tempPrint).find('.ad-image-for-print').show();
            if($(this).data("printing")!=='large'){
                $(tempPrint).find('.descriptionDel').remove();
            }
            parentPrint = tempPrint;
            parentPrint.show();
            parentPrint.printElement();        
        });
```